# Подключение модулей nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить ошибки?

```
Error:(1, 22) TS2307: Cannot find module '@nestjs/common' or its corresponding type declarations.
Error:(2, 32) TS2307: Cannot find module '@nestjs/common/interfaces' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Comment: установить эти модули (yarn add/npm i) и их type declarations

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как именно установить эти модули?

Comment: `yarn add @nestjs/common @nestjs/common`

Comment: Не получается. Есть три файла typeorm.utils.d.ts ошибка в строке import { Type } from '@nestjs/common';

Comment: typeorm-options.interface.d.ts ошибка в строке import { Type } from '@nestjs/common';

Comment: typeorm.module.d.ts ошибка в строке import { DynamicModule } from '@nestjs/common';

Comment: Как возможно исправить?

Comment: не знаю. возможно, сделать то, что советуют в этом [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/4318)